# How to generate custom app metrics/monitoring for celery and prometheus

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I'm trying to generate custom application metrics in celery, and pull them into prometheus. I'm using [danihodovic/celery-exporter](https://github.com/danihodovic/celery-exporter/) to export the celery task metrics, and those are working out of the box. However I cannot find a way to generate custom application metrics (e.g. count of internal method calls, latencies of methods, etc.). I've used the standard [python prometheus client](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python) successfully in a flask application, but I can't make it work in celery.

I can see that celery monitoring is tied with [celery events](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.events.html), however publishing custom events does not show any new metrics in the prometheus exporter.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

from celery import Celery
from celery.events import EventDispatcher
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from kombu import Queue
from prometheus_client import Counter

QUEUE_INPUT = 'test_queue'
TASK_NAME = 'test_task'
QUEUE_ARGS = {'x-queue-mode': 'lazy'}
QUEUE_CONN_STR = os.environ['RMQ_MASTER_CONN_STR']

__LOG = get_task_logger(__name__)

# Define our consumer object
app = Celery(TASK_NAME)

# Define routes
app.conf.update({
    'broker_url': "{0}".format(QUEUE_CONN_STR),
    'task_routes': {"test_celery.test_task": {"queue": QUEUE_INPUT}},
    'task_serializer': 'json',
    'task_send_sent_event': True,
    'worker_send_task_events': True,
    'result_serializer': 'json',
    "broker_pool_limit": 20,
    "task_always_eager": False,
    "result_expires": 2,
    'worker_enable_remote_control': False,
    'worker_prefetch_multiplier': 1
})

app.conf.task_queues = [
    Queue(QUEUE_INPUT, queue_arguments=QUEUE_ARGS),
]

c = Counter('test_counter', 'Number of hits')
d = Counter('test_counter_1', 'Number of msgs')
dispatcher = EventDispatcher(app.connection())
print("Hi")
dispatcher.send("C_INIT")
c.inc()


@app.task(name="test_task", bind=True, max_retries=2)
def test_task(self, payload: dict):
    d.inc()
    dispatcher.send("START_PROCESSING")
    print(payload)
    dispatcher.send("END_PROCESSING")
```

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61113027/custom-metrics-from-celery-workers-into-prometheus?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resorted to using the [prometheus push gateway](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#exporting-to-a-pushgateway). Still searching for a better metrics framework for celery.

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution? Using the push gateway will collect individual metrics for every worker, which is unsatisfactory, and the aggregating gateway by WeaveWorks is outdated and incomplete... Can it really be that nobody running Celery collects metrics??

Comment: @MoritzFriedrich unfortunately no. There is a package https://pypi.org/project/celery-prometheus-exporter/ but it only exports celery queue metrics